# Function to calculate length of a string in Google Spreadsheets when the string contains certain UTF-8 characters

Tags: google-spreadsheets, utf-8, string-manipulation

This function returns 6 and it's expected to return 4:

```
=LEN("AB")
```

What function should I use to get the "real char count" expecting that one symbol in the UTF-8 icon map is 1 character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find such a built-in function, but the result of LEN() is "correct" in that it *asks your browser* how long the string is and returns 6 because the browser's answer to `"AB".length` is also 6.

Although Google Spreadsheets works with *Unicode,* it doesn't actually work with UTF-8 – it works with UTF-16 strings that JavaScript provides, and because  (U+1F94E) has a codepoint above U+FFFF, it won't fit in a single 16-bit code unit but has to be stored as a [surrogate pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java) (U+D83E U+DD4E). The four-character string is therefore stored not as four UTF-8 runes but as six UTF-16 code units:

```
U+D83E U+DD4E U+0041 U+D83E U+DD4E U+0042
```

Unfortunately, UTF-16 code units is exactly what's counted by the [String.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) method in JavaScript (which is an unfortunate quirk that several "early Unicode adopter" programming languages kept for backward compatibility as the world migrated from strictly-16-bit UCS-2 to UTF-16). If you ran `"AB".length` in any JS console, it would also return 6.

(There is another function `LENB()` that *does* encode the string to UTF-8 and returns its length in bytes, but that doesn't help much.)

If you're able to use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), it should be possible to write a custom function that does this (although not using the example in MDN, as Apps Script runs an older JavaScript version that doesn't support strings as iterables). For example:

```javascript
function LENU(str) {
  var length = 0, i, c;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    c = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (c < 0xDC00 || c > 0xDFFF) {
      /* Count everything except low surrogates, as they always
       * (in valid UTF-16, at least) follow a high surrogate that
       * just got counted previously. */
      length++;
    }
  }
  return length;
}
```

*(Note: Double-check the character code range and don't accidentally type 0xDB00 like I just did.)*

This should be usable as `=LENU(...)` from within a spreadsheet, although it is a bit slower due to invoking a remote call to Apps.